# Can a MOSFET conduct no current while in saturation mode?

Tags: voltage, mosfet

[image]

The two transistors are N-MOS.

I have to plot the VTC of this inverter. In order to determine VOH, I set Vin=0.

Since there is no current flow through Q1 (it's in cutoff,) there won't be any current flow through Q2 (assuming a steady state.)
Is it correct to say that Q2 is in saturation and its source voltage is 8.8V?

This leads me to a more general question. Can a MOSFET conduct no current even when it's in saturation mode?

Answer (score 1):

Saturation doesn't depend solely on Vgs, but also on Id. In your situation V2 is so high that the channel of Q2 is formed (I assume enhancement mode devices), so source and drain of Q2 are connected by the low-resistance channel.

However Q1 is off and, assuming ideal behavior (no leakage), Id is 0 for both devices.

Therefore Q2 is not in saturation, but in ohmic region with Id=0 (assuming no load is connected to the output).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the terminal connections of Q2. If V2=Vdd then Q2 is saturated and current is flowing from its drain to its source and out to Vout, but if Q1 is interlocked and Vout remains floating no current may be flowing.